# slightly complex many-to-many linq query got me stuck

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

So I'm on Linq-To-Entities with an asp.net mvc project.

I always get a little stumped with this sort of query.

My schema is:

```
ProductTag
+TagName
+<<ProductNames>>//Many-to-many relationship

ProductName
+FullName
+<<Tag>>//Many-to-many relationship

PurchaseRecord
+Amount
+<<ProductName>>//one productname can be linked to Many purchase records.
```

I need to get the **sum of all purchases for a given tag.**

This is what I've tried.

```
ProductTag thetag//could be some tag

decimal total = myentities.PurchaseRecords
                    .Where(x => thetag.ProductNames.Any
                         (a => a.FullName == x.ProductName.FullName))
                         .Sum(s => s.Amount);
```

I've tried changing a couple of things, tried using `Contains`, but I know I'm fundamentally wrong somewhere.

I keep getting :

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'ProductName'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

**Update**
So with [@Alexandre Brisebois](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18619/alexandre-brisebois)'s help below it worked simply like this:

```
var total= item.ProductNames.SelectMany(x => x.PurchaseRecords)
                                             .Sum(s => s.Amount);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get this sort of error, you need to do all evaluations outside of the linq query and pass the values in as variables.

the problem with your query is that `thetag.ProductNames.Any()` is out of context.

This evaluation is not converted to SQL since it is not a string/guid or int.

You will need to query for this object within your query and evaluate from this object.

I'm not sure if that was clear.

You would need to do something like

```
var query1 = (from x in tags where x.tagID = id select x.ProductNames)
                                                          .SelectMany(...)
```

The select many is because you are selecting a collection `ProductNames` and need to bring it back as a flat set/collection fo that you can do a `.Any()` on it in the next query.

Then use this and do an `query1.Any(logic)`

```
decimal total = myentities.PurchaseRecords.
                           Where(x => query1.Any
                                (a => a.FullName == x.ProductName.FullName))
                                .Sum(s => s.Amount);
```

By doing this you will stay in linq to entity and not convert to linq to objects.

The `ForEach` is not an option since this will iterate over the collection.

Comment: sorry if my code wasn't clear. `GetAll()` is just my repository calling the `entitiescontext`. Updated question. Can you please give a little example on your first sentence? What would I pass in?

Comment: ok I think I get it, but that means I would have to do something like `foreach(item in tag.ProductName) => find the PurchaseRecords that have the item ` right?

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Very much Alenxandre this worked: `var total= item.ProductNames.SelectMany(x => x.PurchaseRecords).Sum(s => s.Amount);` I've still not grasped in my head how I would write this as a linq query (the query notation) but I've very happy it works.

Comment: glad I could help you out on this one :)

Comment: just edited your answer a bit, added some formatting, hope its alright! =) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use AsEnumerable method to perform certain portions of query in C# rather than on sql server. this is usually required when you have part of data in memory (Collection of objects) so using them in query is not easy. you have to perform part of query execution on .net side. for your problem plz try

```
decimal total = myentities.PurchaseRecords.AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(x => thetag.ProductNames.Any
                         (a => a.FullName == x.ProductName.FullName))
                         .Sum(s => s.Amount);
```

plz visit this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/05/25/using-asenumerable-hint.aspx) to find more about AsEnumerable

Comment: this may cause his performance problems if there are many PurchaseRecords since it will query for all the PurchaseRecords from the table.

Comment: yes this will. good solution is not to bring objects in memory in first place unless you really need them. but if you want it this way, this is the solution